# JWT (JSON Web Token) with PHP and Angular.js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, jwt

I have an Angular.js application and I am trying to implement authentication to my PHP backend using a JWT.

I have the app setup to set the token on login and send the token with every request if it exits. I was following the information here, though it is for Node.js not PHP: https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/.

The information there was extremely helpful, but I do not understand why the token should be in the Authorization header with the text 'Bearer ' before the token. Could I just put the token there without 'Bearer '? Is there a recommended method for where the token should go in the request?

My other issue is where to store the token on the front end. The website recommended using $window.sessionStorage which doesn't seem to work well for my case because it seems to prevent someone from using multiple tabs which isn't very intuitive.

My question really comes down to:

- Where do I put the token in the request header?
- How should I store the token on the front end?

Comment: The docs of JWT for PHP is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the `Bearer` keyword is recommended in the [RFC6750 - section Authorization Request Header Field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1):

> Clients SHOULD make authenticated requests with a bearer token using
> the "Authorization" request header field with the "Bearer" HTTP
> authorization scheme.  Resource servers MUST support this method

The libraries I've been working with always require it before the token itself. So the request header should be as follows:

`Authorization: Bearer your_token`

Regarding the storage I have seen it in `$window.sessionStorage` too